# Is there any way to avoid duplicating attributes in this code?

Tags: java, struts2

Hi i want to know if exist a way to avoid duplicate code in this code. Now i have an action class named CustomerAction this class handle the behaviour of the request (it's like a controller) and i have a CustomerPOJO with attributes like id, name, last_name etc. Now i have to add attributes to CustomerAction to handle the data submited from the form. Is there any way to bypass the action with my CustomerPOJO ?

```
public class CustomerAction {

private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private String dni;
private String fechaNac;
private String obraSocial;
private String nroAsociado;
private String plan;
private String password;
private String email;
private String telParticular;
private String telCelular;

private static final Log log = LogFactory
        .getLog(CustomerAction.class);

public String execute() throws Exception {
    if ("cancelar".equals(this.getAccion())) {
        log.debug("Executing 'cancelar' action");
        return "login";
    }

    if ("registro".equals(accion)) {
        log.debug("Executing 'registro' action");
        IReferenceDataBusinessDelegate ud = new ReferenceDataBusinessDelegate();
        ud.signCustomer(this.getNombre(), this.getApellido(),
                this.getDni(), this.getCorreo(), this.getContrasena());

        return "login";

    }
}
```

---

```
public class Customers implements java.io.Serializable {

private long id;
private String dni;
private String name;
private String lastName;
private String email;
private String password;
private String phone;
private String cellphone;
private Date birthDate;
private Date creationDate;
private Date lastAccessDate;
private byte active;
private Set<Profesionales> profesionaleses = new HashSet<Profesionales>(0);
private Set<Pacientes> pacienteses = new HashSet<Pacientes>(0);

public Customers() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use `ModelDriven`, and use a `Customers` as the model.

http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/model-driven.html

You'll need to make sure the `"modelDriven"` interceptor is in your stack.

How/where to initialize the model depends on your particular usage scenario; you can do it in a getter as shown in the docs, in a `prepare()` method if you need to reload it from the DB, etc.

I'm not sure what you mean by "bypass the action."

Please note that the ad-hoc dispatch mechanism implemented here with the `accion` parameter duplicates functionality provided by Struts 2 using the `method` attribute of the action configuration. I don't recommend using ad-hoc dispatch mechanisms as it makes understand program flow more difficult than necessary.

Comment: Thanks Dave, what I meant by "bypass the action" is, not use action like controller AND dto. thanks for your answer

Comment: @Agusti-N Using a form object, whether it's under `ModelDriven` or not, is the canonical way to do that.